# Google Plus issue

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, google-plus

I have build an application to fetch all Google plus users from a Circle. I have authorized the client id for two scopes. I am trying to fetch all the users with an Ajax call which returns all the users in a JSON object .But to make it run , i have to have to manually call the servlet for Google Authorization  using www.profileapp.appspot.com/SampleServlet. Is there a way to authenticate with the JQuery call itself ?

```
  $.get('SampleServlet',{skill:$skill},function(obj) {   
    if( obj.jname.length ==0)
        {     
        }
    $("#mytable tr").remove();
    for(var i=0;i<obj.jname.length ;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj.jname[i]+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+obj.jgender[i]+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+obj.jskill[i]+"</td>";
        var td4="<td><a href='"+obj.jurl[i]+"'><img width='78px' src="+obj.jimgurl[i]+"></a></td></tr>";
         $("#mytable").append( tr+td1+td2+td3+td4); 
    }         
   });   
});
```